# why are my javascript floating point numbers getting sliced up?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array filled with latitude and longitude pairs pushed like this

```
doneDotsA.push(lat+"|"+lon);
```

the values can look like 51.5 or -0.11666666666666667, etc.

then the array is stored in a cookie as an array.

when I try to read the cookie contents it looks like this when In examine it

```
alert('doneDotsA='+doneDotsA.toString());
```

yields results like this:

doneDotsA=51.5|-0.11666666666666667

so far so good. however when I try to extract the values like this

```
for (var t = 0; t < doneDotsA.length; t++) { 
    alert('val='+doneDotsA[t]);
}
```

the alert shows 'val=5' then 'val=1' then 'val=.' then 'val=5' etc. somehow reading only one character at a time instead of returning the full number as I'd expect it to do.

does saving an array into a cookie do something to the numbers?

any ideas?

Comment: Your loop is stepping through the string.

Comment: As you are iterating `string` considering `index`, each character from `string`of specified `index` is returned,

Use `String#split`.

Comment: In your extraction, the `doneDotsA` doesn't appear to be an array. Can you please show us the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> stored in a cookie as an array

Cookies are [always stored and retrieved as a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), unless you use custom code to rebuild it into an array after the fact.

Comment: yep, it's stored as a string. var str=readCookie('doneDots'); doneDotsA=str.split("|"); turns it back into an array

Answer (score 0):

A solution like this could be to take your latitude and longitude and put them into a JSON object for serialization and storage in the cookie.  Then you can parse them into objects when the site loads.

```
var coords = {
   points:[
    {lat:12.4444446,lon:44.55555},
    {lat:12.4444446,lon:44.55555}
   ]
};
var serialized = JSON.stringify(coords);
toStore(serialized);
```

Then you can just set it to local store or to anyplace you can store a string.

```
var myLoaded = fromStore();
var coords = JSON.parse(myLoaded);
coords.points.each(function(coord) {
  // do something with points. 
});
```

You should then be able to do something with the points you saved.

One note:  you might want to check that myLoaded is not an empty string or wrap parse in a try/catch block.  A poorly formed structure will throw an exception.